# What numbers do macro- and oligo- correspond to?

Tags: etymology, prefixes, greek

In modern SI system, micro- (Greek: micros) means 10^{-6}, and mega- (Greek: megas) 10^6.

What number does macro- (Greek: macros) mean in SI or outside?

Does oligo- (Greek: oligos) also mean a number?

Answer (score 3):

You can find here [the complete list of SI prefixes](https://www.nist.gov/pml/owm/metric-si-prefixes). Macro- is not a prefix, nor is oligo-.

Macro- is a general English prefix meaning "large scale" but it is not associated with a specific number.

Comment: and oligo- is a rare and unproductive prefix meaning "few" (oligarchy = rule by a few) but again, no specific number.